# Qt 5.6 Unknown Module: QtPurchasing

Tags: qt

I am using **Qt 5.6 Community Edition**. I added `QT += purchasing` in `.pro file` then I added `#include <QtPurchasing>` in the **main.cpp file**. But I get this error:
`:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: purchasing`
Where is the QtPurchasing module?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Qt Purchasing is an add-on library" that is not available in the (free as "free beer") Community Edition. Go down to the page:

http://doc.qt.io/QtPurchasing/

...and/or contact qt.io fro here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/commerciallicense.html

Comment: Thanks, Can I use this module in Qt LGPLv3? I found this module on git service (git://code.qt.io/qt/qtpurchasing.git).

Comment: @İbrahim IANAL nor do I not know this module, but looking at the files `LICENSE.GPLv3`  (I guess for the `examples/`) and `LICENSE.LGPLv3` (I guess for the module itself), it seems you can. Also have a look at the source files preamble. I'd rather go to qt.io for specific licensing requests, you won't find some real insightful legal advice on SO... we're all programmers, not layers.